# serialize variadic list of arguments and messages

Tags: c++, macros

I am trying as to serialize an arbitrary list of argument. For example

```
int a = 5;
int b = 10;
std::cout << EH_SERIALIZE(a, b);
```

should result to `a = 5, b = 10`

this is what I have and it works:

```
#define EH_STRINGIZE(arg) EH_STRINGIZE1(arg)
#define EH_STRINGIZE1(arg) EH_STRINGIZE2(arg)
#define EH_STRINGIZE2(arg) #arg

// Make a FOREACH macro
#define EHFE_1(WHAT, X) WHAT##_FINAL(X)
#define EHFE_2(WHAT, X, ...) WHAT(X) EHFE_1(WHAT, __VA_ARGS__)
#define EHFE_3(WHAT, X, ...) WHAT(X) EHFE_2(WHAT, __VA_ARGS__)
#define EHFE_4(WHAT, X, ...) WHAT(X) EHFE_3(WHAT, __VA_ARGS__)
#define EHFE_5(WHAT, X, ...) WHAT(X) EHFE_4(WHAT, __VA_ARGS__)
//... repeat as needed

#define EH_GET_MACRO(_1, _2, _3, _4, _5, NAME, ...) NAME
#define EH_FOR_EACH(action, ...) \
    EH_GET_MACRO(__VA_ARGS__, EHFE_5, EHFE_4, EHFE_3, EHFE_2, EHFE_1)(action, __VA_ARGS__)

// Example
// Some actions
#define EH_HELPER_SERIALIZE_FINAL(X) EH_STRINGIZE(X) " = " << (X) << "\n"
#define EH_HELPER_SERIALIZE(X) EH_STRINGIZE(X) " = " << (X) << ", "
#define EH_SERIALIZE(...) EH_FOR_EACH(EH_HELPER_SERIALIZE, __VA_ARGS__)
```

the problem is that in case of

```
int a = 5;
int b = 10;
std::cout << EH_SERIALIZE("message", a, b);
```

the result is `"message" = message, a = 5, b = 10` where what I would like the result to be is `message: a = 5, b = 10`

What I need to to do to detect if the first argument is a string literal and somehow change the behavior.